# JUnit 4 not picking up a thrown exception

Tags: java, junit

For some reason; despite me coding in my validation correctly, JUnit 4 keeps raising a failure even if the exception is thrown:

code:

```
 try {
          if (firstname == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("First name cannot be null");
          }catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      e.getMessage();
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

JUnit:

```
 @Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
 public void testUserInvalidConstructions() {
   User user = new User(null);
 }
```

Comment: But you caught the exception right after throwing it.

Comment: @Törpetestű oooh

Answer (score 1):

Just realised catching the exception overrides the throw
nevermind